# How to write a csv vertically with Python?

Tags: python, csv

I want a CSV designed like this:

```
   A      B     C     D   
 ------ ----- ----- ----- 
  v1     v11   v12   v13  
  v2     v21   v22   v23  
  v3     v31   v32   v33
```

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{"v1": ["v11", "v12", "v13"], "v2": ["v21", "v22", "v23"], "v3": ["v31", "v32", "v33"]}
```

I already tried this:

```
with open("cyclesAndSignalChange.csv", 'wb') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, cycle_with_signal_change.keys(), delimiter = ' ')
    for i in cycle_with_signal_change:
        wr.writeheader()
        wr.writerow(cycle_with_signal_change)
```

But this just gives me a 1GB large file whereas my data is like 1MB.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use pandas to manage the records and export it as a csv.

Comment: Why 'vertically'? You have 3 sequences, write those as rows.

Comment: What you're looking for is a `transpose`.

Comment: ***"I have a dictionary like this"***  - No, you don't have valid python dictionary  with `[ "v1": ("v11", "v12", "v13"), "v2": ("v21", "v22", "v23"), "v3": ("v31", "v32", "v33")]`. Change the square brackets `[]` to curly braces `{}` and you'll have a dictionary.

Comment: Are you expecting to output the exact same format as in your post, with the same large amount of whitespace and the `-----` header - rows divider? If so, the `csv` module is the wrong tool anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing your whole dictionary as a row, for every key in the dictionary, so you are outputing an exponential amount of data; the fact you are adding a header *for each row* only upping the damage.

You need to treat each key-value pair as a row here:

```
with open("cyclesAndSignalChange.csv", 'wb') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    wr.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
    for key, value in cycle_with_signal_change.items():
        wr.writerow([key, *value])
```

This outputs the key-value pairs in [arbitrary order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary); if you need to have a specific ordering, sort first or use an ordered data structure.

Comment: This was everything i wanted to know, ty.

Comment: "*This was everything i wanted to know, ty.*" -  We can always learn new things and specially learn to thank others that try to help us. Nice answer @Martijn, it matched op's *wants*.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this task?  i.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
test = {"v1": ("v11", "v12", "v13"), "v2": ("v21", "v22", "v23"), "v3": ("v31", "v32", "v33")}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(test.items(), orient='index',  columns=['B','C','D'])
df.index.name = 'A'
df.to_csv("test.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

---

**test.csv**

```
A   B   C   D
v1  v11 v12 v13
v2  v21 v22 v23
v3  v31 v32 v33
```

---

PS: 
If you need the *fancy* `------ ----- ----- -----` just append it programmatically after the `csv` header, but remember you'll have to skip this line when you parse the csv file.

Comment: Pandas is great if you need it for data analysis. It’s a pretty hefty thing to install just the write a CSV file, where the standard library can already cover this use case just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The last part of your current answer is the reason I  used pandas.

Comment: so `sorted()` is a reason to install Pandas?

Comment: Hahah, no, just  for the sake of simplicity The code above runs under 500ms and, in this case, I don't see the advantage of  importing the `csv` module, assuming that pandas is already installed on the OP system and the OP isn't  *obliged* to use the CSV module.